# Add user on Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am new here and i dont know how to use codeigniter and now im confused. So i am currently trying to add user data to the database using codeigniter 3.1.10 . When i click the " save " button there's nothing to display. The page was refresh

Can you help me please?
Models:

```
    function add_user($data) {
    $this->db->set("username",$data["username"]);
    $this->db->set("password",$data["password"]);
    $this->db->set("indirizzo",$data["indirizzo"]);
    $this->db->set("citta",$data["citta"]);
    $this->db->set("cap",$data["cap"]);
    $this->db->insert("user");
    $ins_id =$this->db->insert_id();
    return $ins_id;
}
```

Controllers:

```
    function add() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('save', '', 'trim|required|number');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) :
        $data = array(
            "username"=>$this->input->post("username"),
            "password"=>$this->input->post("password"),
            "indirizzo"=>$this->input->post("indirizzo"),
            "citta"=>$this->input->post("citta"),
            "cap"=>$this->input->post("cap"),
        );

        $user_id= $this->user_model->add_user($data);
        $this->log_model->scrivi_log($user_id,"user","add");
    $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'User added.');
        redirect("user/pageuser/".$user_id);
    else :  
        $content = $this->view->load("content");
        $content->load("clienti_form","user/add");
        $this->view->render();
    endif;
}
```

Comment: A lot going on here. Your sole form validation rule applies to a field that apparently does not exist (code for the view where the form is submitted would help). Views are loaded with `$this->load->view('file')` (you got view->load mixed up) but also you are assigning the view to a variable (why?) and later treating it as an object which does nothing really useful... what errors are you getting? (not just in the browser, check your logs). Are your form helpers enabled? are you preloading your model before calling it?

Comment: how can i solve ? ç_ç

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function add_user($data) {
  $this->db->insert("user",$data);
  $ins_id =$this->db->insert_id();
  return $ins_id;
  }
```

use this in model..

and in controller set rules for each like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
// for all other
```

Comment: Does not work. The page remains still and if I click on Save ,the page will update.
If I use (if ($ this-> form_validation-> run () == null):
A new user adds me but I can not enter the data

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('save', '', 'trim|required|number'); this line is confusing me.. is it going inside if ($this->form_validation->run()) : this controls echo something and die to check

Answer (score 1):

Your doing a lot wrong, starting from the fact that your doing stuff from the model in your controller, and you should divide it, otherwise your not using the concept of MVC.

Try something like this, being hard to help you, without seeing the whole code:

Model

```
function add_user() 
{
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
    'indirizzo' => $this->input->post('indirizzo'),
    'citta' => $this->input->post('citta'),
    'cap' => $this->input->post('cap')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
}
```

Controller

```
function add() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('indirizzo', 'Indirizzo', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('citta', 'Citta', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cap', 'Cap', 'required');

    $errore = true;

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){ // if doesnt work load your view

            $this->load->view('your view');

    }
    else { 

    $this->user_model->add_user();
        $this->log_model->scrivi_log($user_id,"user","add");
        $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'User added.');
        redirect("user/pageuser/".$user_id);

        $content = $this->view->load("content");
        $content->load("clienti_form","user/add");
        $this->view->render();
    }
}
```

You really should try and search more about it, and learn!
I could learn a lot of the basics of CodeIgniter, watching this channel that has great content, and explains every detail: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-RfqbaP_71rOyChhjeK1swokUIS